# Get a particular char in particular line and store in variable

Tags: shell, awk, sed, grep

I am having a file which contains 2 lines and i want to get the particular char from each line and do some operation.

My File:

```
vm16_DSC_Instance_4 dsc-sig=172.16.17.14;Public=10.10.72.15;dsc-InterInstance=172.16.18.14;dsc-OAM=172.16.16.19
vm19_DSC_Instance_3 dsc-sig=172.16.17.15;Public=10.10.72.14;dsc-InterInstance=172.16.18.15;dsc-OAM=172.16.16.20
```

Requirement:
From this below name i want the number like 4 and 3.

```
vm16_DSC_Instance_4
vm19_DSC_Instance_3
```

Current :
Here i am getting 4 and 3 in one shot. I want to take 4 from 1st line and do some operation then i will take 3 from 2nd line and will do some operation. Basically i want based on counter it will get the 1st or 2nd line char.

```
cat /tmp/tmp_inst_tmp |awk '{print $1}' | cut -d'_' -f4
4
3
```

Comment: Question not clear - `But i want based on the counter it will get the 1st or 2nd number.` ? Post the required ouput

Comment: updated the question

Comment: Why not store the result in array and use it for processing later?

Comment: you can also use `grep -oP '\d+(?= )' /tmp/tmp_inst_tmp` to get the numbers

Comment: Whatever operation it is, you should do the search for the chars AND that operation in awk, not in shell. If you tell us what you're really trying to do we can show you how to do it the right way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an array to store the result and use `sed` for this simple task

```
array=( $(sed -E 's/^[^[:blank:]]*_([[:digit:]]+)[[:blank:]]+.*$/\1/' file) )
for i in "${array[@]}"
do
# Do some task with "$i"
done
```

---

<sup>Mind the [[ useless use of cat ]](http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Another approach with sed and array:

```
while read -r num; do
  arr+=("$num")
done < <(sed 's/^[^ ]*\([0-9][0-9]*\) .*/\1/' file)

echo ${arr[0]}
4
echo ${arr[1]}
3
```

Comment: as there is only one space in given input, `sed 's/.*\([0-9]\) .*/\1/' file` would work too

Comment: @spasic It would work but maybe a bit safer to start from non space characters.